# struct Element { int i; double d; char c; }; suppose starting address is 100; what are the offsets i, d, c will be stored?

Tags: variables, struct, offset

```
struct Element
{
    int i;
    double d;
    char c;
};
```

suppose starting address is 100;
what are the offsets i, d, c will be stored ?

answer is 100,108,116,. but i dont know why.

Comment: Depends on programming language, compiler struct alignment settings, etc. It looks like C or C++, but can you specify a language?

Comment: What language are you talking about?  How do you know what the offsets are?

Comment: In this case, both `int` and `double` parts of the struct seem to be taking up 8 bytes each. I'm guessing you're doing a 64 bit build?

Comment: or the double has 8-byte alignment requirement

Answer (score 0):

By default a compiler makes an alignment and padding for the performance purpose if other not specified by `#pragma`s or somehow else. The aligned data are faster fetched by CPU rather than not aligned.